# How to filter a list by date > [TODAY]

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, filter, date

I have a list for some enterprise events, but I encounter difficulties when attempting to create a view for future events only. The list contains a date_event column which is in the default format, without time.

I have read documentation [use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4).
SharePoint is configured in French, which doesn't help. Date is displayed in default 'dd/mm/yyyy' format:

[image]

If I try to filter using [TODAY] (I do think it's [AUJOURDHUI](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/today-function-e76dd490-0579-453f-8dd3-fbbed4357ff2) in French), I get a popup:

[image]

[image]

I would translate it into *filter value date format not supported* ? How can I display date format? how to add 'dd/mm/yyyy' if it's what I am supposed modify? I tried using DATE(YEAR(date_event), MONTH(date_event), DAY(date_event), 'dd/mm/yyyy'), with translated functions, without success.
How can I filter date columns for dipslaying only the coming events in a list view? What do I miss ?

Comment: What happens when you use `[TODAY]` instead of `[AUJOURDHUI]`? Is it throwing any error or not showing items or is it working fine for you?

Comment: @Ganesh I dot get the exact same popup as with [AUJOURDHUI].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In French, `[TODAY]` is not `[AUJOURDHUI]` but `[AUJOURD'HUI]`!

Check out this [article (auto)translated in French](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/utiliser-le-filtrage-pour-modifier-un-affichage-sharepoint-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4) by Microsoft.

It's working fine on my side.

[image: Today filter]

Comment: Thanks! So funny! I didn't even try [Aujourd'hui], the apostrophe seemed so strange, and [today-function](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/today-function-e76dd490-0579-453f-8dd3-fbbed4357ff2) documentation was mysleading and  conforted me in my biased view! But the autotranslation is indeed correct (Cannot upvote yet, sorry).

Comment: Yes, it's weird to have to use french keyword, furthermore with apostrophe!